# VBA Add Summary sheet for multiple excel sheets and add the subtotals

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple sheet of data that include subtotals for groups of data based on a particualr column. Now I need a vba code that would take the subtotal from x number of sheets and copy the totals to a single summary sheet. As you can see below the code needs to insert a row for the subtotals of "SheetName1" and fill in the subtotals for Column3 Values(A, B and C) of "SheetName1" and the same for the rest of the sheets:

[image]

Comment: Please click on the URL to see the image describing my question.

Comment: Do you have any code so far? If not, what *exactly* is the part of the task which you're having a problem with? "I need a vba code" typically doesn't get much help around here.

Comment: Im not sure how to add the total from each sheet to the summary sheet. Please have a look at the pic I uploaded.

Comment: Are the totals always in the same location?

Comment: No they will change depending on the number of rows.

Comment: same column but the row will change.

Comment: The number of row will change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub tester()

Dim sht As Worksheet, rw As Range, c As Range, i As Long

    Set rw = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) _
              .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "Summary" Then
            i = 2
            rw.Cells(1).Value = sht.Name
            Set c = sht.Range("C1")
            Do While c.Value <> ""
                If c.Value = "Total" Then
                    rw.Cells(i).Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    i = i + 1
                End If
                Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
            Loop
            Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next sht


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It did it however it only carried over 23 and 24 not the 6. Also, where in the code I can specify the location for the total in the summary page?

Comment: If it didn't carry over the 6 then the cell in ColC doesn't have the content "Total". Check for extra spaces. It will add the rows to Summary beginning in the first empty cell in ColA.  Change the `Set rw = ...` line if you want it somewhere else.